# background worker and progress bar implementation for additional column in datagridview?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, datagridview, progress-bar, backgroundworker

still relatively new to C#, im trying to get my head around the background worker and progress bar suited to my app, the following code shows i am adding a new column to a datagridview and then filling all the cells of the new column with a zero (0). what would be the best way to implement the background worker and progress bar for this.
The whole process takes around 15 seconds hence the need for a progress bar to show the user something is happening.

The code for adding and filling the new column is as follows:

```
//Creates new column in the datagridview
        DataGridViewColumn newCol = new DataGridViewColumn();
        newCol.CellTemplate = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell();
        newCol.HeaderText = tbAddSupp.Text.ToUpper();
        newCol.Name = tbAddSupp.Text.ToUpper();
        newCol.Visible = true;
        dgvStock.Columns.Add(newCol);

        cbSuppList.Items.Clear();
        cbSuppList2.Items.Clear();

        //Adds the default 0 value to all the cells in the new column
        //ITS TOO SLOW THOUGH....!!!!!
        int cellVal = 0;
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvStock.Rows)
        {
            for (int r = 0; r < dgvStock.Rows.Count - 1; r++)
            {
                dgvStock.Rows[r].Cells[newCol.Name.ToString()].Value = cellVal;
            }
        }
```

Comment: I think you're asking the wrong question. 'How to make this (appear) faster' would be the correct question...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is slow because you are doing the same loop twice. I think this is enough:

```
int cellVal = 0;
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvStock.Rows)
{
    row.Cells[newCol.Name.ToString()].Value = cellVal;
}
```

In fact if you have just 100 rows your loop was running from 100 * 100 = 10000 times!

Comment: so far my datagridview consists of 4220, so now i know why it was taking so long, thank you for pointing this out, its working instantly now and no need for the bgw or progress bar. Thank you so much.